# jqm's page transition, blank page

Tags: jquery-mobile

i'm developing hybrid app using JQM + PhoneGap on Android.

when i change the page, i want to show transition effect like slide or slideup etc...

it works fine except Android 2.x version. (i have realized this issue in JQM docs : [this is JQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html))

so i made custom trasition. but it doesn't work fine.

when i change the page with transition effect using my custom transition CSS.

it shows 'blank page' between 'A page' and 'B page'.

this is my code : [http://jsfiddle.net/vanryuji/4DkEv/3/]

how can i delete(?) or hide(?) this page?

Comment: It might be easier to understand if you state the problem and scenario first then show the code.  Also clean up syntax, explanation etc...

Comment: Made a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xGgu6/ Since I don't have your custom code, it does not run. Can you include your JQuery/JS Code?

Comment: @bryanmac - thanks your comment and i'll rewrite my question ^^

Comment: @Twisty - i didn't know about jsfiddle.net. it's cool, thank you

Comment: Ok, I see the blank part of your transition. I think this comes from the CSS transitions. It has to perform the slide out left first, once that is done, it will then do the slide in right. Tinkering with your fiddle now and will see if I can come up with something.

Comment: In the jquery.mobile.transition.js, there is a handler that detects sequential versus simultaneous. I have a suspicion that your slide is performing in sequential, slide out to left followed by slide in from right. Need to make this run as simultaneous, such that slide out to left and slide in from right happen at the same time. Researching if this can be set via CSS or if it requires call the transition via JQuery.

Comment: @Twisty - Twisty!!! i'm done ^^ this is new code: http://jsfiddle.net/vanryuji/p3j52/3/ i really appreciate your help and your advice about jsfiddle, really thx

Comment: @ByeongsooKim Awesome! Feel free to mark my answer below. I started seeing people use jsfiddle here a lot and it's a very useful testing tool and way to share code examples.

Comment: @Twisty is that right?? checking like this '√'. it's my first time to ask on stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you got it. When you ask a question, you can mark an answer as the best answer and others can upvote answers as well. I have been enjoying helping people with things and also use it as resource for my own projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the way you are performing the Slide, [JQM](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/1.2/docs/pages/page-customtransitions.html) has this to say:

> During a CSS-based page transition, jQuery Mobile will place the class
>   name of the transition on both the "from" and "to" pages involved in
>   the transition. It then places an "out" class on the "from" page, and
>   "in" class on the "to" page. The presence of these classes on the
>   "from" and "to" page elements then triggers the animation CSS rules
>   defined above. **As of jQuery Mobile version 1.1, animation class
>   additions are queued, rather than simultaneous, producing an
>   out-then-in sequence, which is friendlier for mobile rendering than
>   our previous simultaneous transition sequence.**

You will need to bypass the `sequntial` action or force `simultaneous`.